# Group by multiple columns, then order results

Tags: visual-studio, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list of a class with several properties, I want to group by 5 of them and then order the results of the grouping by 5 different properties.  The result should be a List().

Lets say (pseudocode-ish)....

```
public class cls()
    string firstSTR {get;set;}
    string secondSTR {get;set;}
    string thirdSTR {get;set;}
    string fourthSTR {get;set;}
    string fifthSTR {get;set;}
List<cls> vals = new List<cls>();
var tmp = PopulateList(); // Here I would populate several hundred cls()

var unique = tmp.GroupBy(i => new {
    i.firstSTR,
    i.secondSTR,
    i.thirdSTR,
    i.fourthSTR,
    i.fifthSTR
 }).ToList().OrderBy (i => new {
    i.firstSTR,
    i.secondSTR,
    i.thirdSTR,
    i.fourthSTR).ToList();
```

I have very limited experience with Linq and I am not able to figure out why this does not work.  The result of the first group by does not return a list of cls so I am not even sure how I can define what I want to order on.  I hope that I have provided enough information to explain what I am trying to do.  Thank you in advance.

----- EDIT -------

Here is what some example data might look like.  I have included 10 columns of sample data however the there are more like 50 columns in the class.

> Last5|First5|Add5|ZipCode|InsuranceName|Policy#|Group#|GroupName|SubscriberName|SubscriberAddress
>
> > SMITH|JOHN|123 M|99523|Medicare|POL123|GRP123|GRPNM|SMITH| JOHN|123 MAIN ST 99253
> >
> > SMITH|JOHN|123 M|99523|Medicare|POL123|GRP123|GRPNM|SMITH| JOHN|123 MAIN ST 99253
> >
> > SMITH|JOHN|123 M|99523|Commercial|POL456|GRP456|GRRNM|SMITH| JOHN|123 MAIN ST 99253
> >
> > SMITH|MARY|992 W|99324|Medicare|POL789|GRP789|GRPNM|SMITH|MARY|992 WEST ST 99324
> >
> > SMITH|MARY|992 W|99324|Commerical|POLXXY|GRPXXY|GRPNM|SMITH|MARY|992 WEST ST 99324

Above there are 5 records, delimited with pipe.  The output data must be unique on the first 5 fields: Last5, First5, Add5, ZipCode, and Insurance name.  Although I am looking to group on these first 5 columns I need all the data in the original class object populated in the result.  My result data should look like this.

> Last5|First5|Add5|ZipCode|InsuranceName|Policy#|Group#|GroupName|SubscriberName|SubscriberAddress
>
> > SMITH|JOHN|123 M|99523|Medicare|POL123|GRP123|GRPNM|SMITH| JOHN|123 MAIN ST 99253
> >
> > SMITH|JOHN|123 M|99523|Commercial|POL456|GRP456|GRRNM|SMITH| JOHN|123 MAIN ST 99253
> >
> > SMITH |MARY|992 W|99324|Medicare|POL789|GRP789|GRPNM|SMITH|MARY|992 WEST ST 99324
> >
> > SMITH |MARY|992 W|99324|Commerical|POLXXY|GRPXXY|GRPNM|SMITH|MARY|992 WEST ST 99324

The result should only have 4 records as one Medicare Records for John Smith has been removed because the first 5 fields are a duplicate of another.  Any other field in the remaining 5 columns (again, 50 or so in my data) can be the same, or different, it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming that you don't want aggregates

```
var unique = tmp.GroupBy(i => new {
    i.firstSTR,
    i.secondSTR,
    i.thirdSTR,
    i.fourthSTR,
    i.fifthSTR
 }).Select(p=> new  {
   firstSTR = p.Key.firstSTR,
   secondSTR = p.Key.secondSTR,
   thirdSTR = p.Key.thirdSTR,
   fourthSTR=  p.Key.fourthSTR,
   fifthSTR =p.Key.fifthSTR,

}).OrderBy(p=> p.firstSTR)
 .ThenBy(p=> p.secondSTR)
 .ThenBy(p=> p.thirdSTR)
 .ThenBy(p=> p.fourthSTR)
 .ThenBy(p=> p.fifthSTR)
 .ToList();
```

Comment: Looking at the result of this in my code I think I am getting the uniques grouped and ordered properly but it's only giving me these 5 properties populated, the actual class is about 50 properties (columns if you will) wide.

Comment: I guess I am trying to replicate something like "SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY firstSTR,secondSTR,thirdSTR,fourthSTR,fifthString ORDRE BY firstSTR,secondSTR,thirdSTR,fourthSTR)  -  please note I am not ordering by the fifthSTR

Comment: Hey @Keht , Grouping  always follow aggregates . im mean you cant just select all from the table  you can only include the column  that are defined in group by  clause other columns needs to be aggregated in order to get included  i.e you must have to use functions like count,max,first

Comment: Can you show some example data (on how you need it) in tabular format for both  before and after query

Comment: Thanks Wamiq!  I could not figure out how to make the data look right with tabs here in stackoverflow so I updated my question with an example of data delimited with pipe.  Hopefully, this is more clear.

Comment: I have reviewed the data a bit.  I believe that using what you had but modified like this works:  var unique = tmp.GroupBy( .... ).Select(p=> first()).OrderBy( .... ) ... Is there anything I ignorant of that would make that not work?

Comment: Yes in this case you can do like this .
 `.Select(p=> new  {
   firstSTR = p.Key.firstSTR,
   secondSTR = p.Key.secondSTR,
   thirdSTR = p.Key.thirdSTR,
   fourthSTR=  p.Key.fourthSTR,
   fifthSTR =p.Key.fifthSTR,
   //Here you include all the other column like this
   ZipCode =p.FirstOrDefault().ZipCode ,
   InsuranceName =p.FirstOrDefault().InsuranceName //And soo on..
})`